# how to set up a check box to pick a level

Tags: javascript

im trying to make check list so the user can pick a difficulty level for a face matching game, but i cant get the numberOfFaces to  change with the selected level in the check box it just ignores the box. so do i use '| |' instead of putting it in an array? its just to have the user pick a level.

```js
           const easy = 5;
           const medium = 55;
           const hard = 100;
          const faceArray= [easy, medium, hard];
          let numberOfFaces = 5;

          const theLeftSide= document.getElementById('leftSide');
          const theRightSide= document.getElementById('rightSide');
      

          function generateFaces(){
              for (let i=0; i < numberOfFaces; i++) {
                const face= document.createElement('img');
                face.src= 'image/smile.png';
                const randomTop = Math.floor(Math.random()*400) +1;
                const randomLeft = Math.floor(Math.random()*400) +1;
                face.style.top = randomTop + 'px';
                face.style.left = randomLeft + 'px';
                theLeftSide.appendChild(face);
              }

              const leftSideImages = theLeftSide.cloneNode(true);
              leftSideImages.removeChild(leftSideImages.lastChild);
              theRightSide.appendChild(leftSideImages);
              theLeftSide.lastChild.addEventListener('click', nextLevel);
              document.body.addEventListener('click', gameOver);
          }
            let num = 0;
          function nextLevel() {
              event.stopPropagation();
              num = num + 1;
              numberOfFaces += 5;
              while (theLeftSide.lastChild) {
                  theLeftSide.removeChild(theLeftSide.lastChild);
              }
              while (theRightSide.lastChild){
                  theRightSide.removeChild(theRightSide.lastChild);
              }
              generateFaces();
          }

          function gameOver() {
              if (!confirm('You got' + ' ' + num + ' ' + 'right do you want to play agin?')) {
                 generateFaces(); 
              }else {
                location.reload();
              }
              document.body.removeEventListener('click', gameOver);
              theLeftSide.lastChild.removeEventListener('click', nextLevel);
          
            }
```

```html
<body onload='generateFaces()'>
      <h1>'Matching Game'</h1>
      <p>'Click on the extra face on the left.'<p>
      <div id='leftSide'></div>
      <div id='rightSide'></div>
      <div id='myModal' class='modal'>
      <input  type = 'checkbox' id = 'easy' name = 'easy' value = 'easy'>
      <label for = 'easy'>Easy</label>
      <input type = 'checkbox' id = 'medium' name = 'medium' value = 'easy'>
      <label for = 'medium'>Medium</label>
      <input type = 'checkbox' id = 'hard' name = 'hard' value = 'hard'>
      <label for = 'hard'>Hard</label>

      </body>
```

Comment: Use a button group https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_type_radio.asp to start.

Answer (score 0):

As a different starting point would this help? With a button group, only one level can be selected.

```js
var numberOfFaces = document.querySelector('input[name="level"]:checked').value;
console.log(numberOfFaces);
```

```html
<!-- 
    'name' is the same for all buttons, which makes them a group.
    the first one is marked 'checked'.
 -->

<input type="radio" id="easy" name="level" value="5" checked>
<label for="easy">EASY</label>
<br>
<input type="radio" id="medium" name="level" value="55">
<label for="medium">MEDIUM</label>
<br>
<input type="radio" id="hard" name="level" value="100">
<label for="hard">HARD</label>
```

Comment: it didnt work it got rid of the faces and checkmarks